# is it possible to run several different war files on the same Tomcat instance?

Tags: java, tomcat, vps

I am currently using a cloud based solution (couldbees.com) to run my 3 web apps (Java, very small scale). It works fine but cost is an issue (close to 70 euros per month, for not even 2Gb of RAM used and no storage!). I would like to switch: take a VPS hosting solution, install Tomcat on it, and run my web apps on it.

My newbie question is simply: can you run simultaneously several web applications on the same Tomcat server, installed on a VPS? I suppose so, but I'd just like to get a confirmation to be sure!

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. They would run on different context paths.

So,

```
http://yourdomain.com/app1
http://yourdomain.com/app2
```

You could also set up subdomains to route there based on what configuration options you may or may not have available.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [tutorial](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412) on Hosting multiple websites with Apache2